# How To Open Homescreen Activity for Selecting Launcher in OPPO or Other Phones

Tags: android, launcher, application-settings, android-launcher, app-launcher

Hello Friend I'm working on Launcher Application. for select my launcher as Home app a popup is showing in samsung. by using this code.

```
 private void launchAppChooser() {
    PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager();
    // get dummyActivity
    ComponentName componentName = new ComponentName(context, DummyActivity.class);
    // enable dummyActivity (it starts disabled in the manifest.xml)
    packageManager.setComponentEnabledSetting(componentName, PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED, PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);

    // create a new (implicit) intent with MAIN action
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    // add HOME category to it
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    // launch intent
    startActivity(intent);

    // disable dummyActivity once again
    packageManager.setComponentEnabledSetting(componentName, PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED, PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);

}
```

but this code is not working on OPPO and HUAWEI. I'm using following line for showing same popup to select home launcher

```
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent,"Select Launcher App"));
```

This code is showing popup with launcher Apps but when i clicked on any app its not set as default.
Can i open homescreen Activity from setting in OPPO for choosing default launcher like this(please open image). because CM Launcher app is opening this activity
[Clicke here to open image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eyQzc.png)
Now i Want To Open This Activity Programetically. and Need Yours help for doing this.

Answer (score 0):

For checking in oppo devices, you have to check if the current default home app package name contains `"oppo.launcher"`.

After that, use this code using it. You can open the default home apps settings in "oppo devices"

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(Settings.ACTION_HOME_SETTINGS);
startActivity(intent);
```

This is an alternative solution for changing the current home app to your launcher app. This intent redirect user to default launcher app list in oppo devices.